# How to use Jquery for sliding effect

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery.
I have written some javascript code for some client validation.

```
document.getElementById(spnError).style.display = 'block';
```

This is how I am showing a span if there is some validation issues in the form. I want to use Jquery to show this span. I would like to slide it down  slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a variable for the ID, you need the [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), like this:

```
$('#' + spnError).slideDown('slow');
```

without the `#` if `spnError` is say `"mySpanElement"`, it's looking for that tag name, `<mySpanElement>`...to search by ID prepend a `#` to it :)

You can [read more about jQuery selectors here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me:_Using_selectors_and_events) and [view a complete list here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Thanks. Although I figured it out myself. It was easy.

Answer (score 1):

Replace milliseconds with how long you want it to take

```
$("#spnError").slideDown(milliseconds);
```

There are also three built in values

```
$("#spnError").slideDown("slow");
$("#spnError").slideDown(); //default speed
$("#spnError").slideDown("fast");
```

Comment: Slight correction, there are [three built-in values](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L455), `slow`: 600ms, `fast`: 200ms,  and the default: 400ms.

Comment: @Nick @Malfist Thanks. it worked. But I want to pass a  string variable which will contain my spanid. $(#spnError).slideDown("slow");